# Problem with installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I just upgraded the current version on Nvidia drivers to a recommended version and then tried to reboot  it.

I installed it using the software center in Ubuntu.

But upon rebooting I am having trouble logging in. It shows a dialog box that says system running on low graphics. What should I do now?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using, what did you do to upgrade the drivers, and which graphics card do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 16.04 and  I updated the drivers using the software updater . I have a 940MX . Sorry for not mentioning them before